# How do you work out percentages?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've started to learn Python and I'm trying to build a simple salary app. What am I doing wrong? The total should be £55,000 times 24 percent, divided by 52 weeks and should equal to 216.666666667 but I am getting a total of 0.25384615384615383

```
my_salary = 55.000
my_taxes = 24 /100
my_weeks = 52
my_total = my_salary*my_taxes/my_weeks
my_total
0.25384615384615383
```

Comment: 55'000 is **not** equal to `55.000`, `55.000` is `55` (the `.` is the decimal dot). Note that you calculated the amount of taxes you pay per week, not the amount that is left for you per week.

Comment: I believe that North America uses the decimal point differently than do some other places in the world. Here we use the comma to separate thousands (e.g. 1,000) and the period to separate out fractional pieces (e.g. 1.25). I believe some other places do the opposite. However, in addition, in your case you should just write "55000". If you write "55,000" I believe your program will crash as Python will try to interpret that as a string.

Comment: @Ben: if you write it as `55,000`, Python will interpret it as a tuple. If this is Python-3, so `(55,000)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, Willem. Do you need the parentheses to make it a tuple or will it get interpreted that way without them?

Comment: @Ben: no, even without parenthesis Python will do that. For instance if you write `return 55,000` this will return a tuple as well.

Comment: @willem: so it's (salary/weeks*taxes) and change to 55000

Comment: No, it is `salary*weeks*(1-taxes)` and changing `salary` to `55000`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my_salary = 55.000
```

is your problem. You've defined a float with the value of 55.000 (fifty-five), not 55,000. Change this line to

```
my_salary = 55000
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's also told about `.` as a decimal separator. I want to add:

If you are using Python 3.6+ you may use `_` as a thousands separator to make you numeric constants more readable:

```
my_salary = 55_000
```

Test here: https://repl.it/OCwJ/0